# Proper way to prepare variable-length data for Keras stateful RNN training

Tags: deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am training Keras RNNs to generate articles. During training I feed in articles of variable length. It all goes fine with stateLESS RNNs.

I wanted to try to train Keras stateFUL RNN, but stateful RNNs in Keras require inputs and outputs of length proportional to batch size, so if I set batch size for example to 256, how do I then feed in articles of length 100, 200, 350 etc?

I can concatenate several articles, but even if their length is greater than batch_size, I need to pad inputs and outputs somehow if concatenated article length is still not proportional to the batch size. What is the proper way to do it?

For now I am just padding the articles with some placeholder characters like this:

```
...
model.add(LSTM(...stateful=True...)
model.compile(...)
...
# batch_size = 15
article = 'hello world'
x = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '_', '_', '_', '_', ]
y = ['e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', ]
model.fit(...)
model.reset_states()
...
# next article etc.
```

But I am worried that the model learns meaningless things from these 'tails'. Is it OK, or should I do something else?

(I am not concatenating alot of articles, because I am afraid that the model will try learn the nonexistent dependencies between them, if I don't reset states inbetween feeding in too many of them)

Comment: Do you have a reason to use stafeful=True?

Comment: @Daniel Möller I want the model to learn longer short term dependencies, as I understand if I set stateful=False it will only learn dependencies that appear inside of a single batch (am I wrong?)

Comment: The only way to learn longer sequences is to input longer sequences. Stateful is not used to improve a layer's "memory" or to change how the net learns in any way. It's used to allow you to divide a very long sequence in smaller sequences and pass this long sequence in parts instead of passing it entirely. Instead of passing the entire "hello world" sequence, you will start passing parts of it: batch1 = "hello ", batch2 = "world". Then the stateful layer will understand that both batchs form a single sequence "hello world".

Comment: yes, that is what I meant, but how to pad the last smaller sequence correctly? e.g. if your batch size is 10 and your first sequence is 'hello worl' and the last is therefore 'd' how do you pad this 'd' sequence so the net won't be 'confused'? Am I doing it right?

Comment: If it's alone in the batch (like batches with only one sample), you don't need to, as long as you define your `batch_input_shape` with `(1, None, Features)`. -- But, are the sequences long enough so you need to split them? Using this approach is really unecessary extra work if you can pass the entire sequence at once.